# How to find the total number of people who live in a ward 5 miles or less from a closed bank?

Tags: qgis

I am currently using QGIS 1.8.0 and need some assistance with a 'Select by Location' query.

I have a data layer showing all UK wards (containing data on ward names, areas and populations) and another with all bank branches. I have run a query to find all the bank branches that have closed. I now want to run a query to find the total number of people who live in a ward 5 miles or less from a closed bank. Please advise as to how to do this.

Comment: Buffer your closed bank branches with a 5 mile radius - then clip to your wards - recalculate your population by area. The population is loosely based on residence (2011 census)